# ¿Está el "español neutro" definido y regulado de alguna forma?

Tags: español-neutral

El otro día en la sala de chat [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061?m=41069498#41069498) se hizo referencia al español neutro.

Nunca he sabido exactamente que era eso del español neutro, aunque tenía una idea aproximada, así que busqué algo de información; la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_neutro) por ejemplo dice:

> El **español neutro** o **castellano neutro**, también conocido como **español global** o **español internacional**, es un estándar artificial del idioma
>   español con el que se pretende deslocalizar el lenguaje y que se
>   acomode, si no a todos, al máximo sector posible de la población
>   hispanohablante con el fin de ser empleado por medios de comunicación
>   y entretenimiento.

La definición es más o menos lo que imaginaba pero la duda es ¿quién define ese estándar? y también ¿hay algún organismo que lo regule? o ¿hay documentación accesible al respecto para saber qué palabras o expresiones se consideran neutras?

Esas son algunas de las dudas que me surgen sobre este tema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vaya por delante que yo tengo (o tenía hasta hace un rato) las mismas dudas que tú, así que me he puesto a indagar.

#### Definido: sí, más o menos.

Consultando las referencias que aparecen al final del artículo de la Wikipedia que has enlazado, me encuentro lo siguiente (negritas mías):

> **Caracterización del español neutro**
>
> El fin principal del **español neutro, cuya ley fue sancionada en mayo de 1986 en Argentina**, es comercial. Se procura que el producto sea exportable a la mayor cantidad de sectores del mercado y por eso se busca una lengua que prescinda de las peculiaridades nacionales. Para la elaboración de la ley así como para su cumplimiento, no se consultó a ningún especialista en temas lingüísticos.
>
> La ley presupone la existencia de un español neutro y de un proyecto unificado acerca del mismo. El artículo 1 , (único dedicado a la consideración del concepto) dice:
>
> *«El doblaje deberá ser realizado en idioma castellano neutro, según su uso corriente en nuestro país, pero comprensible para todo el público de la América hispanoahablante».*
>
> Una reglamentación dos años posterior amplía así:
>
> *«Se entenderá por idioma castellano neutro al hablar puro, fonética, sintáctica y semánticamente, conocido y aceptado por todo el público hispanohablante, libre de modismos y expresiones idiomáticas de sectores».*
>
> <sub>Petrella, Lila: [*El español «neutro» de los doblajes: intenciones y realidades*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/obref/congresos/zacatecas/television/comunicaciones/petre.htm#caracterizacion). Centro Virtual Cervantes.</sub>

De lo cual extraigo que el "español neutro" es un intento de crear una variedad de español que pudiera sonar medianamente bien a los oídos de los 450 millones de hispanohablantes.

La fuente anterior, sin embargo, solo describe el dialecto a grandes rasgos, no lo define.
Para ello, tenemos que irnos a otra de las fuentes del artículo, donde por ejemplo se explica:

> **3.1. Plano fónico:**
>
> El sistema del español neutro se compone de 17 fonemas consonánticos (...) es
> seseante, no existe el fonema interdental /Ө/. Tampoco aparece el fonema palatal lateral
> /ʎ/.
>
> (...) el
> consonantismo es fuerte y estable, no existe velarización de nasales, pérdida de
> consonantes implosivas, ni confusión de -r/-l.
>
> **3.2. Plano morfosintáctico**
>
> (...) La segunda persona es siempre *tú*, nunca *vos*, y el plural de *tú* es *ustedes*.
>
> Es constante la falsa pluralidad del CD; es decir, el uso de *se los-las* por *se lo, se la*, cuando se sustituye a un CI plural: *Mi hija se los va a explicar* (a ustedes). *Esa protección se las daré yo* (a mis hijas); y la ausencia del pronombre de CD con algunos verbos: *Tu padre no sabe que nosotras sabemos*, *Quiero ver quién va a explicarle a la pobre Julianna* (eso).
>
> También aparece el interrogativo *cuál* como adjetivo: *¿Cuál difunto?*
>
> Las oraciones de relativo hendidas se construyen con *que*, cualquiera que sea el antecedente: *Es precisamente de eso que quiero conversar*, *Por causa de ella fue que le pasó*, *¿Qué es lo que no quieres que mi hija se entere?*, y las
> fórmulas interrogativas directas introducidas por *cómo* se refuerzan con *ser + que*: *¿Cómo fue que cerraste tu discurso?*, *¿Cómo es que lo sabré?* Además, la fórmula *es que* pierde el verbo: *¿Que no hay cena en esta casa?*
>
> <sub>Llorente Pinto, Mª del Rosario: [*¿Qué es el español neutro?*](https://gredos.usal.es/jspui/bitstream/10366/121976/3/DLE_LlorentePinto_Que_es_espanol_neutro.pdf) [PDF]. Universidad de Salamanca.</sub>

Lo anterior es solo un extracto, el PDF enumera muchas otras características. No obstante, no deja de ser un estudio descriptivo, es decir que no define el español neutro como tal sino que explica sus rasgos en base al uso observado del mismo en películas y textos.

#### Regulado: no parece.

Más allá de la ley argentina mencionada ([Ley N° 23.316, de 1986, sobre doblaje](http://servicios.infoleg.gob.ar/infolegInternet/anexos/20000-24999/23775/norma.htm)), no parece que el **español neutro** sea regulado, ni siquiera reconocido, por ninguna entidad oficial relacionada con el uso de la lengua.

Hay varios indicios a tener en cuenta:

- una de las críticas que se le hacen a la ley es que no se contase con la opinión de los lingüistas;
- no se encuentra información al respecto en el sitio de la RAE;
- no existe una definición "oficial".

Todo ello da a entender que el español neutro es una variedad del lenguaje desarrollada sobre la marcha, al margen de las academias y expertos, y basándose más en lo que funciona o no a nivel de mercado: los elementos que el público rechace por demasiado regionalistas serán eliminados o adaptados, y los que sean entendidos por todos quedarán fijos.

Lo que sí está regulado es el **[español estándar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_est%C3%A1ndar)**, que [no debe confundirse con el español neutro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_est%C3%A1ndar#Espa.C3.B1ol_est.C3.A1ndar_y_espa.C3.B1ol_neutro_o_espa.C3.B1ol_global), y que se refiere [según el DPD](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-es) a lo siguiente:

> **Es por ello la expresión culta formal la que constituye el *español estándar***: la lengua que todos empleamos, o aspiramos a emplear, cuando sentimos la necesidad de expresarnos con corrección; la lengua que se enseña en las escuelas; la que, con mayor o menor acierto, utilizamos al hablar en público o emplean los medios de comunicación; la lengua de los ensayos y de los libros científicos y técnicos. Es, en definitiva, la que configura la norma, el código compartido que hace posible que hispanohablantes de muy distintas procedencias se entiendan sin dificultad y se reconozcan miembros de una misma comunidad lingüística.
>
> A pesar de la imposibilidad de dar cuenta sistemática de todas las variedades que de uno y otro tipo puedan efectivamente darse en las distintas regiones de habla hispana, el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* trata de orientar al lector para que pueda discernir, entre usos divergentes, cuáles pertenecen al ***español estándar* (la lengua general culta)** y cuáles están marcados geográfica o socioculturalmente.

Según Wikipedia, esta norma culta se basa en una u otra variante del español según la zona:

- El español de España (o europeo), para España y resto de Europa.
- El rioplatense para Argentina, Paraguay y Uruguay.
- Un estándar basado en el mexicano para el resto de países americanos.

Quizá haya cierto solapamiento entre el español estándar de América y el español neutro o internacional, pero sería en todo caso un solapamiento natural provocado por compartir zona geográfica, no porque se le aplique ninguna regulación al español neutro.

Comment: Entonces aquellos doblajes, que me parecían tan extraños, de dibujos animados que veía de pequeño eran "español neutro".

Comment: ¿deberíamos entonces tener un tag "español-estándar" en lugar de "español-neutral"?

Comment: El artículo que citas habla de una ley argentina porque es una investigación sobre el tema en Argentina. De ninguna manera el español neutro es una creación "del gobierno de Argentina"