# ¿Qué es el español internacional? ¿Cuál es su diferencia respecto al español?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, español-neutral

En el sitio de Uber, en la sección donde se puede cambiar el idioma vi que para español no usan la palabra sola "Español" sino "Español Internacional".

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los dos?

Comment: Muy relacionado: [¿Está el “español neutro” definido y regulado de alguna forma?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23207/1674)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El término "español internacional" se refiere a un conjunto de reglas de alfabetización en sistemas informáticos; se opone generalmente a "español tradicional". Es parte de la configuración de idioma.

En el "español internacional" (que en sistemas Microsoft se suele llamar en inglés *Spanish (modern sort)*), las palabras se ordenan alfabéticamente tomando en cuenta el orden del alfabeto latino básico (el usado en inglés), sólo que con la *ñ* después de la *n*; las vocales acentuadas no se consideran caracteres especiales.

En el "español tradicional" (*Spanish (traditional sort)*), el orden es igual, excepto que los dígrafos *ch* y *ll* se tratan como letras y se ordenan alfabéticamente luego de la *c* y de la *l* respectivamente. Este tratamiento es el que seguía el alfabeto español desde el Diccionario de la Real Academia de 1803 y hasta 2010. Es decir, al ordenar una lista con las palabras *calle, chato, cura*, el orden tradicional era *calle, cura, chato*; al ordenar *libro, lleno, luna*, el orden tradicional era *libro, luna, lleno*.

Eso es todo lo que significa esta diferencia, que como ves, es muy pequeña y sólo afecta casos donde una aplicación tiene que mostrar listas ordenadas de palabras. Esta configuración no afecta en nada al vocabulario. Tampoco tiene nada que ver con la elección de la disposición del teclado, donde también puedes encontrar diferencias (en general en todos los sistemas hay un teclado *Español* y otro *Latinoamericano*, que se diferencian por la posición o existencia de la *ñ* y la *ç*, además de ciertos signos).

Comment: Wow gracias. Es que yo me mismo cuando le vi pensé que se dice que hay una lista de reglas on palabras que son convenidos por el todo mundo. Y además, entendí sólo de leer la palabra que la significa de Internacional es más como el estándar como ‘el español universal’ o algo así pero lo que trajiste es igual de interesante

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel, si consideras que esta es la respuesta correcta a tu pregunta, puedes marcarla como tal. En la parte izquierda, bajo el número de votos que ha recibido, verás una marca de aceptación que puedes seleccionar para ello.

Comment: No creo que me entendiste correctamente - me sorprendió a aprender que no es así como pensé @Gorpik